# C# - DotNetZip throwing a "Cannot access a closed file." exception while extracting to memory

Tags: memory, stream, zip, dotnetzip

I am attempting to extract a file into a memory stream but keep getting a "Cannot access a closed file." exception. I am using DotNetZip and have the following stack trace:

```
at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.SetFdpLoh()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.get_FileDataPosition()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalOpenReader(String password)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.OpenReader()
```

Here is the segment of code that is throwing the error:

```
            foreach (Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry zipEntry in zip.Entries)
            {
                if (zipEntry.FileName == "PS/DEANS.svg")
                {
                    //wait!
                }
                Logger.WriteToLog(zipEntry.FileName);
                string _extension = FileUtil.GetFileExtension(zipEntry.FileName);
                if (fileExtensionsLowerCase.Contains(_extension))
                {
                    string _fileName = FileUtil.GetFileName(zipEntry.FileName, "/", false).ToUpper();
                    string _folderName = FileUtil.GetParentFolder(zipEntry.FileName, "/").ToUpper();

                    // Extract the file to a memory stream 
                    using (var entry = zipEntry.OpenReader())
                    {
                        entry.LeaveOpen = false;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[entry.Length];
                        entry.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(entry.Length));
                        byte[] digest = Common.GetSha256Digest(buffer);
                        svgCollection.Add(new SVG { fileName = _fileName, folderName = _folderName, fileHashDigest = digest });
                        digest = null;
                    }
                    _fileName = _folderName = _extension = null;
                }
            }
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what may be throwing the error? I am fairly certain that I am not trying to open the same file twice as I am using a foreach on the zip.Entries collection. I'm not sure if this is a DotNetZip issue or if it's my code?

The issue only occurs when I attempt to extract the specific file "PS/DEANS.svg".